# Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R command not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, refactoring, resharper

I'm attempting to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command within Visual Studio 2008 to rename a variable.  I get an error message at the bottom saying that

"The key combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) is bound to command (&Rename...) which is not currently available."

I am not running it or anything I can think of which might prohibit modifications of the file and the F2 command allows a rename to happen.  Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT:  I do have Resharper installed but was previously able to do this with the same setup, I recently migrated computers.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing the following:

1. Go to *Resharper* → *Options* menu commmand
2. Select *Environment* → *Keyboard & Menus*
3. Select the Visual Studio option under *Keyboard Shortcuts*
4. Click *Apply Scheme* and *Save*

This will cause <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to do a rename. (Select ReSharper options in the dialog box that pops up then.)

However, it made <kbd>F2</kbd> no longer able to preform a rename. I was able to fix that by doing the following:

1. Go to *ReSharper* → *Options* menu command
2. Select *Environment* → *General*
3. Select the ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA under *Restore ReSharper keyboard shortcuts*
4. Click *Apply* or *OK*

This allows both <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> commands to work for renaming a variable.

This seems to be specific to ReSharper being installed with Visual Studio, I don't know what the solution would be to fix this if ReSharper weren't installed.

[image: ReSharper Options Menu]

Comment: It appears I don't have ReSharper so I'm still looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Chucky you can map the keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio by going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, looking up Refactor.Rename under the "Show commands containing:" field, and setting it to CTLR + R, CTRL + R under "Press shortcut keys:"

Comment: I found it under 1. resharper->options 2. Keyboard & menus 3. Select Visual studio and press "Apply scheme", 4. Click Save

Comment: Just to add sometimes you need to restart Visual Studio for this to take effect. Certainly I did in VS2013

Comment: If it doesn't work, try to uncheck "Hide overridden Visual Studio menu items". It worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

### For Resharper 6

You should:

- Select menu "Resharper" - "Options..."
- Select "Visual Studio Integration"
- Choose "Visual Studio" in both places
- Click "Apply Scheme"

It will either works or you will have a selection to do (Visual Studio or Resharper), if it is so, then choose Resharper.

Comment: Thanks! It helped. Resetting to Visual Studio lets you choose Resharper then (when shortcut conflicts arise).

Comment: I never thought setting to visual studio would allow me to use resharper commands.. Strange how that works...

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was solved by clearing the ReSharper cache. This can be done in the options menu under `Environment > General` here:

[image: Screenshot of options menu]

Comment: That's Good Point!

Comment: Equally, I tried tons of things above but **before** clearing ReSharper cache I closed files and Visual Studio and reopened. Seemed to work. Annoying! But hey, problem solved :)

Answer (score 4):

resharper has multiple default shortcut bindings that is chosen the first time you start visual studio after instalation.  My guess is you picked a different one this time.

Comment: This was helpful in fixing the problem.

Comment: @mwright - be sure to mark a solution if it helped you solve the issue.

Comment: @CrimsonX - while helpful it wasn't actually the solution, I guess what's protocol on that?  You mark it as solution and then update your post to include the steps for the solution or create your own answer?

Comment: @mwright. A good question. If I were in your situation, and found a detailed answer with the help of myself, I'd answer my own question, mark it as the answer, and thank (and upvote) people that helped you find the solution. Its a judgment call...

Answer (score 3):

Using version 8 of ReSharper in Visual Studio 2013, I had to

1. Go to the RESHARPER menu -> Options
2. Expand **Environment**
3. Select *Keyboard & Menus*
4. Choose **Visual Studio** as the *ReSharper keyboard scheme*
5. Click **Apply Scheme**...Save & close dialog box.

The next time I executed a keyboard shortcut it prompted me to choose which keyboard shortcut I wanted to use.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing very few people will be in my situation but FWIW I was in this situation too where Refactor.Rename (Ctrl+R,Ctrl+R) was *NOT* working in Visual Studio 2019/Win 10, after reboots/restarts plus I did not have Resharper installed. **In my case Refactor.Rename wasn't working because my project was in FOLDER mode not SOLUTION mode (OMFG). Soon as I used the solution tool to "Switch Views" and went into SOLUTION mode Refactor.Rename started working again.** In hindsight this makes sense of course but some kind of error message/warning would have been nice to help me realize what the issue was!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me once. I had to reinstall Resharper (repair from Add/Remove programs probably) to get it to work. But that was with VS2005 though.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers above are well and good but this error also comes up in one more instance.

---

You start debugging your test script written for the project , the project stops at breakpoint .

*If at this point , you try any operation on code , you will get the error similar to :*
**"The key combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) is bound to command (&Rename...) which is not currently available."**

Comment: So, the answer is: stop your debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has worked for me until I have tried upgrading my Resharper! :O

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was I hadn't started the Resharper evaluation which wasn't obvious because all of the Resharper extension options were accessible, but the clue was under:

Extensions -> Resharper -> Why Resharper Is Disabled.

Click "Start Evaluation" (in the same location as "Pause Evaluation" in the screenprint)

[image]

I expected the evaluation to start when I clicked "OK", but clearly it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0 with Resharper 2022.2.2), I had to

1. disable Resharper
2. restart Visual Studio to make the change effective
3. enable Resharper
4. restart Visual Studio to make the change effective

Comment: "to make the change effective" ...what change specifically did you make that resulted in this solution working for you?

Comment: @CollinBarrett: Disable R# and restart Visual Studio so that it is disabled. Enable R# and restart Visual Studio so that it became enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the shortcut used by Resharper. Is there any chance Resharper is not running?

Alternatively, you can change the name, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and then use *Rename*.

Answer (score 0):

You get this behaviour in Visual Studio (without R# installed) if the editor window does not have focus when you issue the shortcut. I've just tried it with R# installed and it does the same thing.

Give the editor focus (ie. by clicking in it) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

**For DevExpress:**

- Open the *Options* screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)
- Go to *Core* → *Features*
- Set *Default to Visual Studio shortcuts*

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by me not clicking 'Accept" on the terms and conditions page, but closing it. I did not realize it was the terms and conditions, and thought it was just a notice, or a 'readme' being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Visual Studio.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I had to reset my resharper settings in the end.

1. Go to Resharper -> Manage Options
2. Click the "Reset All Settings" button

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the text,  Next press `Ctrl` key and then press `R`
   key twice.
2. release `Ctrl` key.
3. Now type the new text and then to apply press `Enter`.