# issue while commenting the code in visual studio 2012

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2012, if I am trying to comment the code using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then it is showing "the key combination (ctrl+k,ctrl+c) is bound to command(command section) which is currently not available."

How can I comment the code?

Comment: this link might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327844/vs-2008-intellisense-missing-the-key-combination-is-bound-to-command-which-is-n
and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547915/ctrlr-ctrlr-command-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard:
Then type in `Show commands containing` textbox one of the following:

- Edit.CommentSection
- Edit.UncommentSection

[image]